# Simulate QMouseEvent on unfocused windows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

So i have a simple application and i'm trying to simulate a mouse click and it's working. But it's only working if the window is focused.
Is it possible to simulate clicks in Qt on an unfocused window?

```
events = [
            QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseMove, QPoint(x,x), Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoButton,
                        Qt.NoModifier),
            QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress, QPoint(x,x), Qt.LeftButton,
                        Qt.LeftButton,Qt.NoModifier),
            QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, QPoint(int(x,x), Qt.LeftButton,
                        Qt.NoButton,Qt.NoModifier),
        ]

window = QApplication.focusWindow()

for evt in events:
    QApplication.postEvent(window, evt)
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: I've managed to get something going ... by activating the window and raising it. But i wonder if there isn't a way to make the window receive the click event even without focus.

Comment: Get `window` another way. You are getting the focus window now, so obviously your postEvents are going only to the focused window.

Comment: @DavidChing tried some other ways. But this is the only way it's working. If i try to send events to the mainwindow it fails.